# Left Join 3 Tables and Show True or False on Empty Cells

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

Ok, this may be confusing so I hope I explain it correctly.

I have 4 tables:

business
photos
video
category

I want to display "featured" businesses on the home page (or elsewhere) and I want to show a Yes or No in the table row based upon whether or not there are photos or videos for that business.

Example: Joes Crab Shack has no videos or photos but is featured. So, when his row is echoed out it will show the Business Name and Business Owner but there will be no data in the photo or video cells thus in the video and photos column it will say No. Otherwise, if the opposite was true, it would say Yes.

[Here's my pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eDXYX58y)

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps it might be better to have separate functions since on the individual business pages I will be listing photos and videos anyway. Maybe I'm making this harder then it needs to be? Since I will need to have functions that query for videos, photos, and specials anyway, would it be possible to while the initial table is being displayed to check the db for the presence of these items? In other words, when the row for Joes is being echoed, a function runs to check for photos, etc? But how would it know to check for Joes and not Bobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this.

What I would do is, when generating the table for display of "featured" businesses I would make a call to your database, the one generally made when generating the photos and videos categories and check the output. If there is something there then have it say yes, if the return from the database is null, it's a safe assumption there aren't any photos or videos and thus you can print out a No.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I posted an answer to the problem below but since it was your suggestion I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat a little with something like this:

```
SELECT b.[other stuff],
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM photos WHERE busid = b.id) AS photo_count,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM videos WHERE busid = b.id) AS video_count
FROM business AS b [etc]
```

`photo_count` & `video_count` will return 0 or greater than 0 - easy enough to get no/yes from in PHP.  That would also stop the duplicate results you'd get from having more than 1 photo/video per business.

*Caveat!*: converting that to the ORM you're using... I'm not sure an ORM would be okay with it.  But if it's not barking over the "AS" aliasing in `from()` & `join()`, maybe you can sneak the subqueries in `select()` without any problems.

Comment: Would it make more sense to have a separate function that checks for photos or videos based upon the b.id?

Comment: You mean in a PHP function?  That might be cleaner, but I doubt it would have a positive effect - one query is speedier than the same split into 3, if only because it's calling out to the DB once.

Comment: ok, just wondered. i'm having an issue with doing the select counts using activerecord. i wondered if maybe i was trying to do too much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that your photos and videos tables contain more than 1 record per business, a "one to many" relationship.

In this case you're going to need to rethink your approach or at least do some formatting of your database results. Currently if Joes crab shack has more than 1 videos and/or photos you're going to have multiple results for Joes crab shack.

If you need photos/videos results you could format the results as you are receiving them now to create a multi dimensional array/object where `$featured['videos']` or `$featured['photos]` would contain the results of your join, if your formatted array doesn't contain the 'videos' key then you have no video results.

If all you need to know is if it's returning more than 0 rows then create two new methods in your model to count videos and photos that belong to a specific business. Now it's just a matter of echo'ing 'Yes' if the methods return more than 0 rows or 'No' otherwise.

Edit: Model function should look something like this

```
function frontPageList() {
    $this->db->select('b.busname, b.busowner, b.webaddress');
    $this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM photos WHERE busid = b.id) AS photo_count', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM videos WHERE busid = b.id) AS video_count', FALSE);
    $this->db->from ('business AS b');
    $this->db->where('featured', '1');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: Eventually what I want to do is have an individual business page where all the photos and videos will be listed. but, on the list of buisnesses page I just want to show if they have things like photos, or videos, or specials/coupons. Would I be better off having separate functions, one for showing the business info, and then separate functions checking for photos and videos and specials and either showing yes or no in the list and showing the actual results on the business page?

Comment: The query you have now is fine for displaying the business info, you just need to format the results into a multi dimensional array before outputting it to your view.

You're likely going to need a count function in your model at some point in your project, you can create those now and use them or use the suggested nested query from tadamson.

I'll edit my answer with an example of how to use the nested query with CI's Active Record

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that the tables are set up sort of like this:

1. Business Info
2. Photos
3. Videos
4. ?

You would create a unique ID for each business (autoincrement works nicely) and whenever a photo or video is uploaded for the business that record would be inserted into the respective tables with that ID attached to it (the ID column or whatever).

Each table would allow multiple entries for the business ("one to many" as Dyllon noted).

So whenever you are displaying the featured business you would run a query against both the video and photo tables using the unique ID and look for returned rows.  Rows = yes, !rows = no.

One question:
Are you going to store the images in the db or file names and have them uploaded to a directory?

The only other input that I would add to the above recommendations is to structure your tables so that there are never any null values in the tables themselves, which may be the case seeing as you have four tables for this project already.

I second the multi dimensional array/object method of storing and sorting through the returned data.

A nice touch would be to use the PHP image functions to resize the first image returned as a thumbnail for the photos - you could also catch a frame for each video as well - so instead of yes or no, we would seem thumbnails for both or a 'no images/video' slug.

Not much, but my $.02.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.busname
     , b.busowner
     , b.webaddress
     , IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM photos p WHERE p.busid = b.id), 'Yes', 'No') has_photo
     , IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM video  v WHERE v.busid = b.id), 'Yes', 'No') has_video
  FROM business b
 WHERE b.featured = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I was able to do to solve the problem based upon suggestions from you guys:

**Model:**

```
function frontPageList() {
    $this->db->select('b.busname, b.busowner, b.webaddress, p.photoname, v.title');
    $this->db->from ('business AS b');
    $this->db->where('featured', '1');
    $this->db->join('photos AS p', 'p.busid = b.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('video AS v', 'v.busid = b.id', 'left');
    return $this->db->get();

}
```

**Control:**

```
function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Business_model');
        $data['featured']   = $this->Business_model->frontPageList();
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $data['page_title'] = 'Welcome To Jerome - Largest Ghost Town in America';
        $data['page'] = 'welcome_message'; // pass the actual view to use as a parameter
        $this->load->view('container',$data);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<table id="businessTable">
    <thead><tr><th>Business Name</th><th>Business Owner</th><th>Web</th><th>Photos</th><th>Videos</th></tr></thead>
        <?php foreach ($featured->result() as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row->busname?></td>
                <td><?=$row->busowner?></td>
                <td><a href="<?=$row->webaddress?>">Visit Site</a></td>
                <td>
                    <?php if(isset($row->photoname)):?>
                    no
                    <?php else:?>
                    yes
                    <?php endif?>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <?php if(isset($row->title)):?>
                    no
                    <?php else:?>
                    yes
                    <?php endif?>


                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```